# Count the total records containing specific values

Tags: sql, count, case, conditional-statements

I have a question and hope you guys can assist me.

I have a table containing two columns:

```
type           // contains 2 different values: "Raid" and "Hold"
authorization  // contains 2 different values: "Accepted" or "Denied"
```

I need to make a view that returns values like this:

```
TYPE:RAID     ACCEPTED:5          DENIED:7
```

Basically I want to know how many of the values in `TYPE` are "Raid" and then how many of 
them are "Accepted" and "Denied".

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 33):

```
SELECT
   Type
  ,sum(case Authorization when 'Accepted' then 1 else 0 end) Accepted
  ,sum(case Authorization when 'Denied' then 1 else 0 end) Denied
 from MyTable
 where Type = 'RAID'
 group by Type
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `COUNT` in combination with a `CASE` statement

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE authorization WHEN 'denied' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as denied,
  COUNT(CASE authorization WHEN 'authorized' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as authorized
FROM table
WHERE type = 'RAID'
```

`SUM(CASE …)` is also possible, but you'll have to return `0` in the `ELSE` clause instead of `NULL`

Comment: This won't work like this. CASE WHEN needs an END to complete the block.

Comment: @Magisch: yes, you are right. Thanks for pointing it out, I've fixed the snippet!

Answer (score 5):

This code should work for mySQL

```
SELECT type, COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY type;
```

or

```
SELECT type, authorization, COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY type, authorization;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select count(*) as count from tbl_name where type='Raid'
```

for total number of type=raid

Are you saying something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Hey this might help:-

```
select type as 'TYPE',sum(Denied) as 'DENIED',sum(Accepted) as 'AUTHORIZED' from
(
 SELECT type,0 as 'Denied',count(*) as 'Accepted' from t where authorization = 'Accepted'    group by type
 union all
 SELECT type,count(*) as 'Denied',0 as 'Accepted' from t where authorization = 'Denied'     group by type ) as sub_tab group by TYPE;
```

Comment: Hay is for horses.