# Scala Slick: Getting number of fields with a specific value in a group by query

Tags: scala, slick

I have a table like this:

```````````````````````````
|``````````````````````````|
|imgId, pageId, isAnnotated|
|1,      1,       true     |
|2,      1,       false    |
|3,      2,       true     |
|4,      1,       false    |
|5,      3,       false    |
|6,      2,       true     |
|7,      3,       true     |
|8,      3,       true     |
|__________________________|
```````````````````````````

I want the result as:

``````````````````````````````````````
|`````````````````````````````````````|
|pageId, imageCount, noOfAnotatedImage|
|   1          3          1           |
|   2          2          2           |
|   3          3          2           |
|_____________________________________|
``````````````````````````````````````

**I want the number of annotated images based on number field set as true.**

Slick related code I tried which fired exception:

```
  def get = {
    val q = (for {
      c <- WebImage.webimage
    } yield (c.pageUrl, c.lastAccess, c.isAnnotated)).groupBy(a => (a._1, a._3)).map{
      case(a,b) => (a._1, b.map(_._2).max, b.filter(_._3 === true).length, b.length)
    }
    db.run(q.result)
  }
```

Exception:

```
[SlickTreeException: Cannot convert node to SQL Comprehension
| Path s6._2 : Vector[t2<{s3: String', s4: Long', s5: Boolean'}>]
]
```

Note: This [Count the total records containing specific values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998220/count-the-total-records-containing-specific-values) thread clear shows that in plain SQL what I need is possible.

```
SELECT
   Type
  ,sum(case Authorization when 'Accepted' then 1 else 0 end) Accepted
  ,sum(case Authorization when 'Denied' then 1 else 0 end) Denied
 from MyTable
 where Type = 'RAID'
 group by Type
```

Changed the code but still getting exception:

```
Execution exception
[SlickException: No type for symbol s2 found for Ref s2]

In /home/ravinder/IdeaProjects/structurer/app/scrapper/Datastore.scala:60
56  def get = {
57    val q = (for {
58      c <- WebImage.webimage
59    } yield (c.pageUrl, c.lastAccess, c.isAnnotated)).groupBy(a => (a._1, a._3)).map{
[60]      case(a,b) => (a._1, b.map(_._2).max, b.map(a => if (a._3.result == true) 1 else 0 ).sum, b.length)
61    }
62    db.run(q.result)
63  }
64
```

Comment: Why is this tagged SQL?

Comment: Why did you use SQL here?

Comment: Because end of the day Slick will create SQL, and the given exception also refers that

Comment: I guess there is no point trying to argue here. If [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/topusers) says that it's not about SQL, then it's *definitely not about SQL*. It's way too slick-specific, there are so many layers of macros and syntactic sugar that SQL knowledge is mostly useless here.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to see the reputation of @GordonLinoff, and initially I was not sure that such a thing is possible in plain SQL at first place or not

Comment: Your table has columns `imgId`, `pageId`, `isAnnotated`.  I suppose `pageUrl` in your app refers to `pageId` in your table.  What is `lastAccess`?  Does it represent the `imgId` last accessed?  If so, can there be duplicate `imgId` for the same `pageId` in the table?

Comment: actually table has those two columns as well, i didn't show them for sake of brevity

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirement, you should group by only `pageUrl` so as to perform aggregation over all rows for the same page.  You can aggregate lastAccess using `max` and isAnnotated using `sum` over a conditional `Case.If-Then-Else`.  The Slick query should look something like the following:

```
val q = (for {
    c <- WebImage.webimage
  } yield (c.pageUrl, c.lastAccess, c.isAnnotated)).
  groupBy( _._1 ).map{ case (url, grp) =>
    val lastAcc = grp.map( _._2 ).max
    val annoCnt = grp.map( _._3 ).map(
        anno => Case.If(anno === true).Then(1).Else(0)
      ).sum
    (url, lastAcc, annoCnt, , grp.length)
  }
```